# Why does JavaFX media player crash?

Tags: java, javafx, garbage-collection

I have Java 8 installed correctly and it is the oracle version (NOT OpenJDK). My IDE is Eclipse. When I run the following code in a JavaFX project,

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class TestPlayer {
    static JFXPanel fxPanel =new JFXPanel();
    private Media song;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer ;
    public TestPlayer(String filePath) {
        song=new Media(new File(filePath).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(song);
    }

    public void play() {
        this.mediaPlayer.play();
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new TestPlayer("song\\1.mp3").play();
     }
}
```

the `mediaPlayer` can only play song for several seconds, then no sound and no exception thrown.

Then I changed the line 8 from

```
private Media song;
```

to

```
private static Media song;
```

And the modified code ran successfully.

I want to know the reason although the problem solved. These 2 following screenshots are taken in the debug mode of Eclipse

Before modification:
[image]

After modification:
[image: after modification]

The difference is "JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread".

Comment: Adding `static` is unlikely to be the correct fix. Please can you post the stack trace from when it crashes?

Comment: When you add static ,did you create an instance ?!

Comment: The difference made by adding `static` here is that you prevent the `Media` instance going out of scope. I guess that the thread actually playing the media keeps only a weak reference to it. In a real application, this obviously won't be an issue.

Comment: Probably a garbage collection issue.

Comment: I’ll be surprised if any JavaFX classes work properly without a subclass of [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

Comment: @AndyTurner The code just keep running without sound, and no stack trace printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing a garbage collection issue of the media player thread - `JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread`. Iv'e used [VisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) to monitor the threads and GC.

Your code starts the `MediaPlayer` and returns, leaving the instance references eligible for GC. Here I have forced a GC a few seconds after launch (at 6:44:57):

[image]

and at the same time the `JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread` stopped:

[image]

By making the `Media` or `MediaPlayer` `static` you are tying them to the class loader instead of to the class instance, thus they are not eligible for collection. Generally, you should subclass `Application` when using JavaFX classes. The class's JavaDoc states:

> **Threading**
>
> JavaFX creates an application thread for running the application start
>   method, processing input events, and running animation timelines.
>
> The Java launcher loads and initializes the specified Application
>   class on the JavaFX Application Thread. If there is no main method in
>   the Application class, or if the main method calls
>   Application.launch(), then an instance of the Application is then
>   constructed on the JavaFX Application Thread.

When running your code this way, GC can't collect the `JFXMedia Player EventQueueThread`. Again, I initiated a GC (at 7:19:04)

[image]

and now the thread is still alive:

[image]

Notice that the `main` thread is also there along with the `JavaFX-Launcher`.

For a true deep analysis you must inspect a heap dump, but hopefully this insight is enough for the scope of the question.